# Copy an object in Javascript without using Jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to create a copy of a JavaScript object which has enumerable and non-enumerable properties. I want make a exact replica of the object with all enumerable and non-enumerable properties copied to the new one.

Any help how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: already tried it but it did not solve the purpose. object which i want to copy is a nested one, which has a copy of several other objects in it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object.create` or it's backward compatible counterpart.

```
if(!Object.create){
  Object.create = function(o){
    function F(){}; F.prototype = o;
    return new F;
  }
}
var oldObj = {prop1:'val1', prop2:'val2', prop3:'val3'};
var newObj = Object.create(oldObj);
delete newObj.prop2;
console.log(newObj); console.log(oldObj);
```